# Thin Black Border for a Table

Tags: html, css

[image]

I need to have such thin line for the whole table as seen above. The above image is a sample only. My solution, doesn't work. The table shows no border at all.

Here is my CSS:

```
table {
    border-width: thin;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Style the `td` and `th` instead

```
td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

And also to make it so there is no spacing between cells use:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

(also note, you have `border-style: none;` which should be `border-style: solid;`)

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/KbjNr/

Comment: @Petah You don't mention this in your answer, but it's in your JSFiddle: **border-collapse: collapse is the key element to the solution**.

Comment: @JamWaffles well, it will still ave a a 1px solid border around all cells, it will just also have spacing between cells. (updated)

Comment: `echo "<table border=\"1\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\">";` for html if someone would need that

Comment: or `<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse" >`

Comment: When using Madcap Flare, table borders set to .25 px will appear as 1 px until you use border-collapse (i.e., Table Properties > "Cell Border Collapse" >"Collapse Cell Borders" in Flare).

Border Collapse is the key.